# Iterate Hash Map

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I have an hashmap declared as
private HashMap testMessages = null;

I will be storing string values in both key and value part of the hashmap retrieved from oracle table.

I am not concerned about the hashmap keys. I want to retrieve the hashmap values alone  and check whether string variable filename is prefixed with one of the hash map value and return true if it's same.  I want to ensure that hash map values are not null and empty.

function (string filename)
{..

loop thru hashmap values

check whether the variable file name is prefixed with one of the hashmap values if so
 return true
 otherwise 
 return false
 }

hashmap example: 
 key1,prod
 key2,test
 key3,dummy
filename example:
         test123_20012010.csv

should return true since the file name is prefixed with one of the hashmap values

How can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a brute force approach to iterate over the hash map values and check whether filename begins with the value.

```
// generics version
private HashMap<String, String> testMessages = buildMap();

for (String v : testMessages.values()) {
  if (filename.startsWith(v) {
    // found a map value that starts the file name
  }
}

// alternative non-generics version
private HashMap testMessages; // assigned somewhere

for (Object v : testMessages.values()) {
  if (filename.startsWith((String) v) {
    // found a map value that starts the file name
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont want to use buildmap
I am getting compilation errors TestHash.java:20: incompatible types found : java.lang.Object required: java.lang.String for (String prefix : hMap.values()) { Note: TestHash.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. 1 error

Comment: Replace buildMap() with whatever method you use to build the testMessages HashMap. My example uses generics so you wouldn't have to cast the Object instances you get out of the HashMap to a String.

Answer (score 5):

```
for (String prefix : map.values()) {
   if (filename.startsWith(prefix)) {
      return true;
   }
}
return false;
```

It should be noted that this is linear time in the number of entries in the map in the worst case. If you have multiple `filename` that you want to do the check for, it's much better to preprocess the prefixes and build something like a patricia trie and other fast dictionary-like data structures.

Comment: I am getting compilation errors
TestHash.java:20: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.Object
required: java.lang.String
for (String prefix : hMap.values()) {
Note: TestHash.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error

Comment: How did you declare `hMap`? Is it just `HashMap hMap`? What is the type of the keys? Would something like `HashMap<String, String> hMap` work?

Comment: HashMap<Object,Object> hMap = null;
    hMap = new HashMap<Object,Object>();
    hMap.put("1","One");
    hMap.put("2","Two");
    hMap.put("3","Three");

javac TestHash.java
TestHash.java:26: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.Object
required: java.lang.String
for (String prefix : hMap.values()) {
                                ^
1 error

Comment: Looks to me that your keys and values are both `String` types. Then simply use `HashMap<String, String>` instead of `HashMap<Object, Object>`.

Comment: A function retrieving the records from a table and it get's stored as key and value.  Both key and value are varchar2 datatype.  The function retrieve these data  and puts it as String in the below hashmap,
 HashMap<Object,Object> hMap = null; 
 hMap = new HashMap<Object,Object>();
for testing purpose i am writing a sample program and inserting  string values. hMap.put("2","Two"); hMap.put("3","Three");

Comment: If you put them into the map as `String`, then use `HashMap<String, String>` instead of `HashMap<Object, Object>` to take advantage of the type-safety and convenience that generic offers.

Answer (score 0):

leeched from [leepoint.net](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/collections/maps/map_iteration.html)

```
public static void iterate_over_hashmap(Map mp) {
    Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());
    }
}
```

You have to treat each entry as a key/value pair and iterate over those as a single entity. Then you cast it into Map.Entry and then you can read both separately

Comment: It's a hashmap private HashMap can i pass it to a Map?  
private HashMap<Object,Object> testMessages = null;

Can i call  iterate_over_hash(testMessage) ? 

Also how can check whether the variable file name is prefixed with one of the hashmap values if so return true otherwise return false

Comment: He said that he doesn't care about the keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
function(String fileName)
{
     for(String value : hashMap.values())
     {
      if(fileName.startsWith(value))
           return true;
     }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: @polygenelubricants i should take more time to read the question carefully.